# The passed data is missing in model

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my model function contain variables from controller.But that value got from controller.But it is not get into model.

**model**

```
function get_sub_marks_data($division,$subj_name)
{
    $sql = "SELECT student_name,".$subj_name." AS marks FROM f_tbl WHERE
    division='".$division."' ORDER BY student_name asc";
    echo $sql;
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query; 
}
```

**controller**

Post data from ajax

```
 function get_subject_wise_marks()
 {
      $subj_name=$this->input->post('sub');
      $exam=$this->input->post('exam');
       // $classid=6;
        $division='A';

      $subj_name = strtolower($subj_name); 
     if($exam == 't1'||$exam == 't2') 
        {
          $subj_name= $exam.'_10_'.$subj_name;

        }
        else if($exam == 't3'|| $exam == 't4')
        {
            $subj_name= $exam.'_20_'.$subj_name; 
        }
      $sub_marks=$this->IM->get_sub_marks_data($division,$subj_name); 

 }
```

$subj_name the value is not get into model..

Any mistakes in this..

Comment: What is the value of `print_r($_POST)` inside controller??

Comment: print_r($_post) shows Array()

Comment: No post data receive in controller!! check your html form!!

Comment: this data is passed from ajax..i got the posted data in ajax sucess

Comment: Post your ajax code too!!

Comment: Question is updated..Plz check this

Comment: Have you check your browser console for error??

Comment: Have you miss `php` here `<? echo base_url();`

Comment: normaly thats works properly without php

Comment: Use `print_r($_REQUEST)` inside controller and check what you get??

Comment: i got this  
Array ( [/homeindex/get_subject_wise_marks] => )

Comment: It means you are not able to post data using ajax jsu use `<?php echo base_url();` and check!1

Comment: i changed this like url:"<?php echo base_url();?>homeindex/get_subject_wise_marks", but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered to load the model before

```
$sub_marks=$this->IM->get_sub_marks_data($division,$subj_name);  ???
```

Cause I don't see any loading of the model in your code. So try this :

```
 ...
 $this->load->model('IM');
 $sub_marks=$this->IM->get_sub_marks_data($division,$subj_name);
```

Tell me if that worked for you

Comment: i put it in the construct function

Comment: i need ur help.can u?

Comment: you're not in the chat room

Comment: chat link was frozen due to inactivity

Comment: i see so whats to do ?

Comment: after successive two or three comments generate chat link

Comment: oh I see so we need to chat here to create the room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118015/discussion-between-robins-and-arizona2014).

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded model `IM` in your constructor

If not you need to load it like

```
$this->load->model('IM');
```

before calling its function(before below line)

```
$sub_marks=$this->IM->get_sub_marks_data($division,$subj_name);
```